# How to delete all arcs drawn on a Bitmap

Tags: android

I have declared bitmap like this.

```
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
```

Now after drawing some arcs on it, how to clear the bitmap so that it will be in the same state as it was when app started

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
mCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, Mode.CLEAR);
```

[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawColor%28int,%20android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode%29) the documentation.